# Stuck in this question and couldn't understand the code for the sum of subarray

Tags: python, arrays, sum, sub-array

I am stuck in the end function part of the question and arr[start]/arr[end] as well I fail to understand the code. The question is as follows:

> Given an unsorted array A of size N that contains only non-negative
> integers, find a continuous sub-array which adds to a given number S.
>
> You don't need to read input or print anything. The task is to
> complete the function subarraySum() which takes arr, N and S as input
> parameters and returns a list containing the starting and ending
> positions of the first such occurring subarray from the left where sum
> equals to S. The two indexes in the list should be according to
> 1-based indexing. If no such subarray is found, return -1.

```
def subArraySum(arr,n,sum):
    curr_sum = 0 
    start = 0
    end=0
    i = 0
    
    while end <= n-1:
        if curr_sum<sum:
            curr_sum=curr_sum+arr[end]
            end=end+1
        while curr_sum>sum:
            curr_sum=curr_sum-arr[start]
            start=start+1
        if curr_sum==sum:
            break
    if curr_sum != sum:
        return[-1]
    else:
        return start+1, end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is looking for the earliest contiguous sequence that adds up to a given number. For example:

```
1  1  2  4  5  2
```

Is a sequence of 6 numbers. If we are looking for the first sequence that adds to 7, we would end up with 1, 2, and 4, in a subsequence defined by two indices, `start` and `end`:

```
start|
  1  1  2  4  5  2
           end|
```

Note that `end` is one past the end. This is a common convention. Also any given time, `curr_sum` is the sum of all the numbers in the subsequence. In the abovecase, 7.

The code starts with `start` and `end` at 0. As the code loops, if the total of the current subsequence, `curr_sum`, is less than the desired sum, it makes the subsequence longer from front end by moving the `end` up one. If the `curr_sum` is too big, it makes the subsequence shorter by moving the `start` up as many times as needed. If `curr_sum` is the right sum, then it breaks out of function and returns the `start` and `end` indices.

All this said, there's different ways you could track the indices here. Best I can manage, the subsequence is defined by 0-based indices from `start`, up to, but not including, `end`. And then at the end, it returns 1-based indices that include the end index, which is why it's using `start+1, end` instead of `start, end`.

Comment: thank u so much also  end=end+1 or  start=start+1 are supposed to be iterating right?

Comment: Yes, those move the pointer one slot to the right.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> subarraySum(int arr[], int n, long long s)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    
    
    long currSum=0;
    
    while(i<n);
    
    if (currSum==s){
    return{i+1,j};
    
}
if(currSum<s){
    currSum+=arr[j];
    j++;
}
else{
    currSum-=arr[i];
    i++;
 }
 vector<int>v;
 v.push_back(-1);
 return v;
}
```

};

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).